# Upload/update xml files on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have some `.xml` files in a local folder (for example, `C:\xml`). I also have a table in SQL Server with columns `Name` (`varchar`) and `XMLContent` (`xml`).

How can I upload all my files from local folder to SQL Server, compare them and update in case they are different or insert a new entry containing filename without `.xml` and xml content if file is absent on server?

Is it solvable? Maybe there are a ready solution for this action? I'm not very good at SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the perfect solution. It does exactly what I wanted.
[Upload multiple XML files](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3675356/Upload-multiple-XML-files-to-an-XML-data-type-column.htm)